# Has there been an "eventless" English Premier League game?

Tags: football, history, trivia, tournaments, english-premier-league

Has there ever been a game in the English Premier League during which no goals were scored and no cards were shown?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the BBC list of match reports for this. Arsenal v. Sunderland was one such example.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/19221271

Comment: I might have missed it, but where in that article does it say that no cards were drawn?

Comment: If a card is drawn, an icon is shown next to the players name. See here, for example, where Huth and Wilkinson were both booked. http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/19310426